# Derived Class Method hides inherited member

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class and two derived classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    public IEnumerable<Double> Inputs { get; protected set; }

    public BaseClass(IEnumerable<Double> inputs) {

        foreach (Double input in inputs)
            Compute(input);
    } 

    protected abstract Double Compute(Double input);
}

public abstract class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass {

    protected abstract Double Compute(Double input);
}

public class DerivedClass2 : DerivedClass1 {

    private override Double Compute(Double input) {

    // Compute implementation

    }
}
```

I get the error on `DerivedClass1` `Compute` method:

> 'DerivedClass1.Compute(Double)' hides inherited member 'BaseClass.Compute(Double)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword.

How to solve this?

Comment: As the error states, you can override a member without override. Otherwise if it is the same member as the class ot is deriving, dont mention it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to redeclare this method as abstract again, just remove it:

```
public abstract class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass {
}
```

You will need to provide a constructor though, because `BaseClass` doesn't have a default constructor and requires an argument to be instantiated.

Comment: Alternatively, you could declare it `protected override abstract Double Compute(Double input);` in DerivedClass1, but.. why.

Comment: I removed Compute from `DerivedClass1` before but then I wasn't able to set that method as private in `DerivedClass2`. The error is `'DerivedClass2.Compute(double)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'BaseClass.Compute(double)'`

Comment: @MiguelMoura I believe the error message in such situation is also self-explaining. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override): "An override declaration cannot change the accessibility of the virtual method. Both the override method and the virtual method must have the same access level modifier."

Comment: Got it ... I was missing something. Solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that can happen with Functions when you inherit classes: Overriding and Hiding.

Hiding is the kind of thing that was invented very early on when thinking up the idea of OOP. So everyone implements. I can not remember having ever used, seen someone use or even seriously *thinking* about using it in code. The main reason to know about it, is to not *accidentally* do it instead of overriding.

Overriding is the way more usefull thing. You use it 99.999% of all cases. The only downside is that the option of overriding has to be enabeled and maintained every step of the inheritance chain that implements the function. If I run into a case where I can not override, there is only one Option: Just encapsulating this in another class that I *can* override.

I am very surprised that hiding has been classes as a Compiler error. However I am also getting 4 **other** errors [in that code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4oDchhGAzKQIbADOALlE2O+VqQCEmrGAGEANsNakA3rQKlF5RhXoAeACIQArsHEwAfKQCSAOwAO29tJmkA5jHZVS5qBHYweMACakRT0gBfeSVlQWExSVZWAApVTR09Q1IASwsrVgBKWRDQpQAzaBhuAAtSGK1dfVT03jSay2tMwjzW0lEIAFtGmBi0xsyaBSVA0lzFV3dPD18WDi4eUkqk9q6eisTq/qtBwmCCOkY5zm5ebCWYKBSANx8JKRxSEHCRe+icg+GJtw8vWbYTotltUOt0rL1gTAGjshvtDnwLldbt43qx+M8NJcbncoqxHnJPqFXDcmB5SBBblArt4oZDVmCPBsqlDtuxsgSWnl2CU3AB3UimGD8gCiCDAMHM7BSEFMMV2hJGeyAA==). Mostly stuff about the accessors not matching overriding/hiding behavior (it must be at least protected and you can not change acessibility afterwards). So it might well be a case where parsing is so tripped up, it starts inventing problems that do not mater.

As long as a class is abstract, you do not need to code out anything. Abstract classes are there to get "step" in the class heirarchy. I have seen abstract classes used for collecting Interfaces and nothing more. The actuall implementation was still 100% the inheritors job. Coding stuff out is entirely optional - not having to code out stuff is usually the goal.